# Align dropdown menu with parent

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

[image]I'm not very experienced on web development and have run across some issue,i am aligning the menu but it not starting from its parent. I am searched and experimented every possible way but i cant figure out where is the problem.
Following is the css

```
.drop {
z-index: 9;
max-width: 361px;
padding-top: 1px;
position: absolute;
display: none;
float: left;
min-width: 200px;
margin: 22px;
padding: 1.2em 0;
font-size: 12px;
list-style: none;
background: #02709be6;
}

.com:hover .drop {
display: block;
}

li.com .drop>li ul {
align-items: center;
top: 22px;
}

.drop li {
width: 100%;
padding-left: 41px;
padding-right: 51px;
display: block;
clear: both;
padding: 1px 1.6em;
line-height: 1.8;
white-space: nowrap;
color: #333;
-webkit-transition: none;
transition: none;
}

nav {
border: 1px solid #000;
border-width: 0 0 1px;
list-style: none;
text-align: center;
font-size: 21px;
}

nav li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 21px;
padding-right: 35px;
padding-left: 35px;
border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
text-align-last: left;
}

.nav {
margin-top: 25px;
color: #000000;
text-align: left;
left: 0;
width: 960px;
height: 24px;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

expected result be should like this[image: s]

Comment: Can you share the html code as well

Comment: I was asking code, not the website!

Comment: should i paste whole page html here?

Comment: Basically you should add a recreate-able code so that people can concentrate only on that issue, so I suggest if you can make a snippet which explains your issue it will be helpful anything more code is not beneficiary and people may not be able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```css
nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 21px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    text-align-last: left;
    position: relative;
}
.drop{
    z-index: 9;
    max-width: 415px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 200px;
    padding: 1.2em 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    list-style: none;
    background: #02709be6;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 100%;
}
```

Remove this code:

```
li #drop-about {
    left: 56vw;
    max-width: 304px;
    min-width: 242px; }

li #drop-dt {
    left: 22.7vw;
}
```